# Connecting wildlfy 9 to remote Artemis JMS (standalone) server

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to connect wilfly 9 to a remote JMS provider (Artemis MQ) started on a different host.

I've taken the standalone-full.xml, and modified so that I've removed all the 'hornetq' stuff, and defined my resource-adapter like the following:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:3.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="artemis-ra-rar">
                <archive>
                    artemis-ra-rar.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="UserName">
                    username
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="ConnectionParameters">
                    host=myremotehost.mydomain.com;port=61613
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="Password">
                    password
                </config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
                        <xa-pool>
                            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>false</prefill>
                            <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                        </xa-pool>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:jboss/artemis/queue/TestQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="TestQueue">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            artemis/queue/TestQueue
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

I've defined an artemis-ra-rar, as it is used for wildfly 10..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- $Id: ra.xml 76819 2008-08-08 11:04:20Z jesper.pedersen $ -->

<connector xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/connector_1_5.xsd"
       version="1.5">

<description>ActiveMQ Artemis 2.0 Resource Adapter</description>
<display-name>ActiveMQ Artemis 2.0 Resource Adapter</display-name>

<vendor-name>Red Hat Middleware LLC</vendor-name>
<eis-type>JMS 1.1 Server</eis-type>
<resourceadapter-version>1.0</resourceadapter-version>

<license>
  <description>
     Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
     contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
     this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
     The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
     (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
     the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
  </description>
  <license-required>true</license-required>
 </license>

 <resourceadapter>
  <resourceadapter-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter</resourceadapter-class>
  <config-property>
     <description>
        The transport type. Multiple connectors can be configured by using a comma separated list,
        i.e. org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory,org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory.
     </description>
     <config-property-name>ConnectorClassName</config-property-name>
     <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
     <config-property-value>org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
     <description>The transport configuration. These values must be in the form of key=val;key=val;,
        if multiple connectors are used then each set must be separated by a comma i.e. host=host1;port=61616,host=host2;port=61617.
        Each set of params maps to the connector classname specified.
     </description>
     <config-property-name>ConnectionParameters</config-property-name>
     <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
     <!-- <config-property-value>server-id=0</config-property-value> -->
     <config-property-value>host=myremotehost.mydomain.com;port=61613</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <!--
  <config-property>
    <description>Does we support HA</description>
    <config-property-name>HA</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value>false</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The method to use for locating the transactionmanager</description>
    <config-property-name>TransactionManagerLocatorMethod</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value>getTm</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>Use A local Transaction instead of XA?</description>
    <config-property-name>UseLocalTx</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value>false</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  -->
  <config-property>
    <description>The user name used to login to the JMS server</description>
    <config-property-name>UserName</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value>admin</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The password used to login to the JMS server</description>
    <config-property-name>Password</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value>password</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <!-- 
  <config-property>
    <description>The jndi params to use to look up the jms resources if local jndi is not to be used</description>
    <config-property-name>JndiParams</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value>java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory;java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1199;java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The jGroups File name</description>
    <config-property-name>JgroupsFile</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value>jgroups.xml</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The name of the channel used on this configuration</description>
    <config-property-name>JgroupsChannelName</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value>my-channel</config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The discovery group address</description>
    <config-property-name>DiscoveryAddress</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The discovery group port</description>
    <config-property-name>DiscoveryPort</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The discovery refresh timeout</description>
    <config-property-name>DiscoveryRefreshTimeout</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Long</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The discovery initial wait timeout</description>
    <config-property-name>DiscoveryInitialWaitTimeout</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Long</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The load balancing policy class name</description>
    <config-property-name>LoadBalancingPolicyClassName</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The client failure check period</description>
    <config-property-name>ClientFailureCheckPeriod</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Long</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The connection TTL</description>
    <config-property-name>ConnectionTTL</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Long</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The call timeout</description>
    <config-property-name>CallTimeout</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Long</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The dups ok batch size</description>
    <config-property-name>DupsOKBatchSize</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The transaction batch size</description>
    <config-property-name>TransactionBatchSize</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The consumer window size</description>
    <config-property-name>ConsumerWindowSize</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The consumer max rate</description>
    <config-property-name>ConsumerMaxRate</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The confirmation window size</description>
    <config-property-name>ConfirmationWindowSize</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The producer max rate</description>
    <config-property-name>ProducerMaxRate</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The min large message size</description>
    <config-property-name>MinLargeMessageSize</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The block on acknowledge</description>
    <config-property-name>BlockOnAcknowledge</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The block on non durable send</description>
    <config-property-name>BlockOnNonDurableSend</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The block on durable send</description>
    <config-property-name>BlockOnDurableSend</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The auto group</description>
    <config-property-name>AutoGroup</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The max connections</description>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The pre acknowledge</description>
    <config-property-name>PreAcknowledge</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The retry interval</description>
    <config-property-name>RetryInterval</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Long</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The retry interval multiplier</description>
    <config-property-name>RetryIntervalMultiplier</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Double</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The client id</description>
    <config-property-name>ClientID</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>Whether the password is cleartext or encrypted, default false</description>
    <config-property-name>UseMaskedPassword</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value></config-property-value>
  </config-property>
  <config-property>
    <description>The class definition (full qualified name and its properties) used to encrypt the password</description>
    <config-property-name>PasswordCodec</config-property-name>
    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
    <config-property-value>org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.DefaultSensitiveStringCodec;key=clusterpassword;algorithm=something</config-property-value>
  </config-property>-->

  <outbound-resourceadapter>
     <connection-definition>
        <managedconnectionfactory-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAManagedConnectionFactory</managedconnectionfactory-class>

        <config-property>
           <description>The default session type</description>
           <config-property-name>SessionDefaultType</config-property-name>
           <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
           <config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</config-property-value>
        </config-property>
        <config-property>
           <description>Try to obtain a lock within specified number of seconds; less than or equal to 0 disable this functionality</description>
           <config-property-name>UseTryLock</config-property-name>
           <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
           <config-property-value>0</config-property-value>
        </config-property>

        <connectionfactory-interface>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAConnectionFactory</connectionfactory-interface>
        <connectionfactory-impl-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAConnectionFactoryImpl</connectionfactory-impl-class>
        <connection-interface>javax.jms.Session</connection-interface>
        <connection-impl-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRASession</connection-impl-class>
     </connection-definition>
     <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
     <authentication-mechanism>
        <authentication-mechanism-type>BasicPassword</authentication-mechanism-type>
        <credential-interface>javax.resource.spi.security.PasswordCredential</credential-interface>
     </authentication-mechanism>
     <reauthentication-support>false</reauthentication-support>
  </outbound-resourceadapter>

  <inbound-resourceadapter>
     <messageadapter>
        <messagelistener>
           <messagelistener-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messagelistener-type>
           <activationspec>
              <activationspec-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivationSpec</activationspec-class>
              <required-config-property>
                  <config-property-name>destination</config-property-name>
              </required-config-property>
           </activationspec>
        </messagelistener>
     </messageadapter>
  </inbound-resourceadapter>

</resourceadapter>
</connector>
```

Wildfly starts without complaining:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
11:47:51,746 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
11:47:51,986 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
11:47:52,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) starting
11:47:53,241 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
11:47:53,248 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
11:47:53,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found artemis-ra-rar.rar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called artemis-ra-rar.rar.dodeploy
11:47:53,320 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:47:53,347 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
11:47:53,361 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
11:47:53,404 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
11:47:53,405 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
11:47:53,416 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
11:47:53,416 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
11:47:53,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
11:47:53,441 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:47:53,465 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:47:53,466 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
11:47:53,466 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
11:47:53,555 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
11:47:53,557 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
11:47:53,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.4.Final)
11:47:53,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:47:53,625 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
11:47:53,635 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
11:47:53,666 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
11:47:53,666 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:47:53,765 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path /Users/xxxx/servers/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/welcome-content
11:47:53,806 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
11:47:53,851 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
11:47:53,936 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
11:47:54,169 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:47:54,235 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
11:47:54,365 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/xxxx/servers/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments
11:47:54,381 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "artemis-ra-rar.rar" (runtime-name: "artemis-ra-rar.rar")
11:47:54,381 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "test-jms.xml" (runtime-name: "test-jms.xml")
11:47:54,523 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
11:47:55,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RADeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) IJ020001: Required license terms for file:/Users/xxxx/servers/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/artemis-ra-rar.rar/
11:47:55,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) IJ020001: Required license terms for file:/Users/xxxx/servers/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/artemis-ra-rar.rar/
11:47:55,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/ConnectionFactory
11:47:55,212 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) IJ020016: Missing <recovery> element. XA recovery disabled for: java:/ConnectionFactory
11:47:55,220 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions] (MSC service thread 1-8) AMQ342000: Attempted to locate a Transaction Manager but none found.
11:47:55,278 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-8) Resource adaptor started
11:47:55,279 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) IJ020002: Deployed: file:/Users/xxxx/servers/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/artemis-ra-rar.rar/
11:47:55,280 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/ConnectionFactory]
11:47:55,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "test-jms.xml" (runtime-name : "test-jms.xml")
11:47:55,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "artemis-ra-rar.rar" (runtime-name : "artemis-ra-rar.rar")
11:47:55,663 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:47:55,664 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:47:55,664 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started in 4224ms - Started 310 of 497 services (229 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

However, when I try to deploy a sample Servlet that should use the queue I get an error complaining about missing default jms connection factory:

```
11:50:45,456 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war" (runtime-name: "wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war")
11:50:45,628 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war
11:50:45,680 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
11:50:45,860 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/TestQueue
11:50:45,872 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war
11:50:45,902 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 2.2.14 (Final)
11:50:45,930 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war
11:50:46,103 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-helloworld-mdb.wildfly-helloworld-mdb.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory]"]}
11:50:46,105 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.wildfly-helloworld-mdb.wildfly-helloworld-mdb.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory]"]}
11:50:46,111 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0010: Stopping weld service for deployment wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war
11:50:46,148 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war (runtime-name: wildfly-helloworld-mdb.war) in 42ms
...
```

Can somebody show me an example how to connect to a remove JMS server which does not involve using HornetQ as a bridge?

KR,
Davide

Comment: By modifying the configuration and setting the ActiveMQRAManagedConnectionFactory to the jndi name: java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory I could start successfully wildfly. However, when starting, I get: AMQ151001: Attempting to reconnect org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivationSpec(...). Seems that it cannot connect successfully to the artemis server, even if the connection parameters are ok.